# Riddle(Tough one): we are siblings, who are we?

Tags: riddle

We are siblings

We follow each other everywhere

But can never touch each other

**Who are we?**

Edit

> CLUE : We live inside your home, good for the summer, bad in the winter

Comment: Judging from the number of answers that seem to fit all the criteria, I suggest you amend the riddle so that the intended answer is more obviously correct.

Comment: I've added a closer clue to the answer :) @Volatility

Comment: I kind of want to reopen this, but it's only because I think I know the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### First Guess

> The Sun and the Moon

We are siblings

> There are several mythologies that show the sun and moon as siblings ([wikipedia lists Apollo and Artemis & Kuat and Iae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twins_in_mythology))

We follow each other everywhere

> Though the moon does not technically follow the sun - it can appear that way to the naked eye and has many times been referenced as such in different mythologies.

But we can never touch each other

> Physics.SE has [some cool diagrams and explanations on the phases of the moon](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/220112/how-can-we-see-the-moon-while-its-between-the-earth-and-the-sun) but the main point is even during a full eclipse the moon and the sun are far, far from each other.

---

### Second Guess

> Fan or Fan Blades more accurately

We are siblings

> The blades could be described as parts of the whole which could be considered brothers or sisters

We follow each other everywhere

> Fan blades typically rotate in a circular fashion (or follow each other)

But we can never touch

> Barring malfunction the fan blades shouldn't touch

Clue:

> Fans are great in the summer but in the winter (unless you live in a tropical climate like me) just make you colder.

Comment: This is what popped into my mind at first!

Comment: no it's not. clue - They are things/people you can touch

Comment: yes, your second guess! fan/fan blades

Comment: Point of fact: The [*right* fans](http://info.bigassfans.com/l/11152/2015-07-22/38m667/11152/135438/Cassidy_White_Paper.pdf) *are* good in the winter. (Disclosure: I work for Big Ass Solutions)

Comment: @EngineerToast it gets up to 80 here frequently during the winter so all fans are good all year round here

Answer (score 4):

Could it be...

> eyes or ears?

But then again, it can be a lot of things...

Comment: no its not, clue --> it's not a body part

Answer (score 2):

This should be it..

> Blades of a fan

EDIT- Explanation

We are siblings

> All the blades are alike and are connected

We follow each other everywhere

> The move in the same circular path, apparently following each other

But can never touch each other

> They obviously don't touch each other

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! Could you edit an explanation for this solution into your answer? Thank you!

Comment: Added, I didn't think that was necessary but thank you for letting me know. The answer seemed pretty obvious to me when I first saw the riddle.
@Emrakul

Comment: No worries, it happens! For future reference, explanations are required everywhere on Puzzling. Thanks for the speedy edits, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 1):

Well if you are not

> eyes or ears

then you can only be

> Bernie Sanders and Donald Trump

siblings on opposite ends of the

> american political spectrum

following each other around on the

> neverending campaign trail

but you can't touch each other

> or else you would mutually annihilate in a blast of bad hair that could flatten a whole city.

Comment: xD lol, hilarious, but not the answer

Answer (score 1):

Are they

> Two opposite poles of a magnet.

Comment: they can't be because they don't always follow each other everywhere.

Comment: Under what circumstance can you pick up one of *my answer* and not pick up the other one?

Answer (score 1):

### First guess

> day and night (or light and darkness)?

### Second guess (after given clue)

> Me and my shadow

- We are siblings:

> Everyone has a shadow since the moment they're born.

- Cannot touch each other:

> Shadows are not material and then cannot touch nor be touched except if you are Peter Pan.

- We follow each other everywhere.
- Great for summer and not so great for winter.
- Not a part of the body (clue given in another answer).
- Closer to you than you think (clue given in comment below):

> I have an air conditioner.

Comment: They're not. You'd be surprised the answer is closer to you than you think

Comment: @elle ok, updated, it was my alternative.